# Two quick Mathematica questions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

1. How do I remove the numbers on the x-axis only not the y-axis?
2. Is it possible to shift the y-axis without shifting the functions? What I mean is, instead of having the y-axis at x = 0, could I have it at x = -5?

Answer (score 5):

With most options controlling axes, you can use a list of two values to specify different behavior for the two axes. How are you currently removing the numbers? The only way I can think of off the top of my head is to manually specify tick locations, without labels, something like this:

```
Ticks -> {{{0, ""}, {1, ""}, {2, ""}}, Automatic}
```

Otherwise you'd have to start munging around with the graphics output, I guess? In any case, whatever you do, you can use a two-element list like that to apply different options to each dimension.

To relocate the axes, you can use the option `AxesOrigin`; in your example, you'd use `AxesOrigin->{-5,0}`.

Answer (score 5):

The tick marks are controlled by either `Ticks`, or `FrameTicks` if `Frame -> True`.  Note, plots like `ContourPlot` and `DensityPlot` have a frame by default (i.e. `Frame -> True`).  The specification for `Ticks` is

```
Ticks -> {<x ticks>, <y ticks>, <z ticks>}
```

where the `z ticks` are only present for 3D plots.  The `FrameTicks` specification is

```
FrameTicks -> { {left, right}, {bottom, top} }
```

Both `Ticks` and `FrameTicks` accept both `Automatic` and `None` to use the default algorithms or have no ticks, respectively. So, to eliminate only the ticks on the x-axis you do

```
Ticks -> { None, Automatic }
```

and for frames

```
FrameTicks -> { {Automatic, Automatic}, {None, None} }
```

If you want to have more control of the exact placement of the ticks, then @Jefromi is correct, you'll need to specify a list.  The [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ticks.html?q=Ticks&lang=en) and [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FrameTicks.html) documentation are worth the read to get a better feel of how to do this.  Be aware, though, that doing anything more complex than listing a few points is something of a black art in Mathematica, and leads to a lot of frustration.

As to your second question, you use `AxesOrigin -> {-5, 0}` as @Jefromi pointed out.